# Trying to copy files in specified path with specified extension and replace them with new extension

Tags: java, file, copy, nio

I have most of it down but when I try to make the copy, no copy is made.
It finds the files in the specified directory like it is supposed to do and I think the copy function executes but there aren't any more files in the specified directory. Any help is appreciated. I made a printf function that isn't shown here. Thanks!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;

public class Stuff {
static String path, oldExtn, newExtn;
static Boolean delOrig = false;

private static void getPathStuff() {
    printf("Please enter the desired path\n");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    path = in.next();
    printf("Now enter the file extension to replace\n");
    oldExtn = in.next();
    printf("Now enter the file extension to replace with\n");
    newExtn = in.next();
    in.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    getPathStuff();
    File folder = new File(path);
    printf("folder = %s\n", folder.getPath());

    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.getName().endsWith(oldExtn)) {
            printf(fileEntry.getName() + "\n");
            File newFile = new File(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileEntry
                    .getName() + newExtn));
            try {
                printf("fileEntry = %s\n", fileEntry.toPath().toString());
                Files.copy(fileEntry.toPath(), newFile.toPath(),
                        REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.printf("Exception");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the new file is created without a full path (only the file name). So your new file *is* created - only not where you expect...

You can see that it'll work if you'll replace:

```
File newFile = new File(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileEntry
                    .getName() + newExtn));
```

with:

```
File newFile = new File(fileEntry.getAbsolutePath()
       .substring(0,
                  fileEntry.getAbsolutePath()
                           .lastIndexOf(".")+1) + newExtn);
```

Comment: You also had you extension appending to the file name before it was truncating the extension, so it was doing old.extA.extB and changing it to old.extA versus changing old.extA to old and then appending .extB.  Alfasin's solution fixes both, I was too slow in the IDE testing :)